# ANDROID - How to use ImageButton

Tags: java, android

so im new in android developing and im trying to make ImageButton just toast to test it, but i cant get it to work :/ I tried more things but nothing was working. can someone please help me?

**fragment_morning.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:id="@+id/myToolbar">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/test_product"
        android:layout_width="223dp"
        android:layout_height="232dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/test_product"></ImageButton>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/test_product"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="2x McMuffin Menu"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MorningActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mcdonaldscoupons;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MorningActivity extends Activity {
    ImageButton imageButton = findViewById(R.id.test_product);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_morning);
        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.test_product);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MorningActivity.this, "click on image button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Something probably is if it doesn't work

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine. Just remove the image button initialization code from outside the onCreate method. Just declare it outside and initialize it inside the oncreate method. Sometimes Android studio acts weirdly. Try creating the new project and add the morning activity code in MainActivity and fragment_morning code in activity_main.

Comment: can you send me how would the code look like when i mess up with the initialization?

Comment: Just use ImageButton imageButton ; instead of ImageButton imageButton = findViewById(R.id.test_product);= findViewById(R.id.test_product); outside oncreate. Inside oncreate no change needed.

Comment: https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/6eed5941846e4e6b83025e2a31406854 did i do it wrongly? becouse it still isnt working :/

Comment: Yes I know how you are feeling right now. Sometimes android studio act weirdly. Your code is fine just try to create new project and copy paste your code . It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code.

```
//activity xml file
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="Click me"
    android:src="@drawable/test_product"
    android:id="@+id/img_btn"/></LinearLayout>


//Activity code
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageButton imageButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    imageButton = findViewById(R.id.img_btn);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click on image button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: no error but it isnt doing anything when clicked

Comment: can the problem be RelativeLayout and LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Replce to

```
Toast.makeText(MorningActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**EDIT**

```
public class MorningActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton imageButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_morning);
        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.test_product);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MorningActivity.this, "click on image button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: still nothing :/

Comment: no error but it not doing anything when clicked

Comment: https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/d29640959dbd449a87daedc677740534

Comment: when you clicking button getting given exception in logcat ? show full  of onclick codes

Comment: no this is when the app is starting when i click button nothing happens in logcat (using category debug in logcat)

Comment: Expand imagebutton onclick code and edit the question

Comment: do you want to send logcat or code? im from czech republic and i dont get you

Comment: please check this out and read step by step , or create new project and follow this https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-toast-with-examples

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a reference the imageButton before the activity gets created ( onCreate gets called when views have been created and inflated)

Views can only be referenced after the activity has been created. Usually you wouold need to have all the findViewByIds call inside onCreate.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_morning);
    imageButton = findViewById(R.id.test_product);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MorningActivity.this, "click on image button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is arising probably because you are extending Activity instead of AppCompatActivity...

Comment: If you don't know how to work with gradle files then create a new project and copy all this code and Make sure the new activity extends AppCompatActivity not Activity.